# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise])

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to render a list of posts by mapping through an array. I've done this many times before but for some reason

```
renderPosts = async () => {
    try {
      let res = await axios.get('/posts');
      let posts = res.data;
      return  posts.map((post, i) => {
        return (
          <li key={i} className="list-group-item">{post.text}</li>
        );
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul className="list-group list-group-flush">
          {this.renderPosts()}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

All I get is:

> Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

I've checked the data returned from renderPosts and it is an array with the correct values and no promises. What's going on here?

Comment: You can only ever return 1 object from react. You need to change return posts.map to const someVar = posts.map, and then return <ul>{someVar}</ul> ... that way, you're returning a wrapped object. https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: while the first comment is true, the larger problem is that you're trying to return JSX from an async method which won't work. you need to fetch your async data in `componentDidMount()` and call `this.setState` when your api returns instead of returning JSX directly

Comment: I tried this before with componentWillMount because I assumed that was the issue but it didn't work. Just did it with componentDidMount and it worked! Thanks azium.

Comment: Obligatory "I know this is old, but...". @azium 's comment saved me. If you run into this... Another dev had thrown an async on the component function. This error did not encourage me to check that... Thanks, azium :)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

`this.renderPosts()` will return a `Promise` not the actual data, and AFAIK Reactjs will not resolve Promises implicitly in `render`.

You need to do it like this

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.renderPosts();
}

renderPosts = async() => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get('/posts');
    const posts = res.data;

    // this will re render the view with new data
    this.setState({
      Posts: posts
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

render() {
  const posts = this.state.Posts?.map((post, i) => (
    <li key={i} className="list-group-item">{post.text}</li>
  ));

  return (
    <div>
      <ul className="list-group list-group-flush">
        {posts}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This is also helped https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/async-await-with-react-lifecycle-methods-802e7760d802

Answer (score 139):

I also received the same error message when creating an async functional component. Functional components should not be async.

```
const HelloApp = async (props) =>  { //<<== removing async here fixed the issue
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Hello World</h2>
    </div>
  )
}
ReactDOM.render(<HelloApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Padhraic/mgt2udbL/5/)

Comment: This fixed it for me - the stacktrace didn't really give away that this was the issue!

Comment: Neither `render` function in a class components can be async i.e return a `Promise`.

Comment: Exactly. Instead of implementing async/await directly on the functional component, I added useEffect hook inside the functional component like this `useEffect(async () => {//code with await keyword here}, [])` and all worked fine

Comment: @EranG the async func' should be inside like this useEffect( () => { async function fetchData(){ //code with await keyword here } fetchData(); }, []);            The useEffect callback cannot be async.

Comment: lifesaver, I was trying to figure out what was causing this error when converting class components to functional and I had made the component async!

Comment: @OmerGreenwald In my case I am using `next.js 13` with functional component as `async` keyword to use `SSR` functionality, so I need to use `async functional component`, but still getting this error.

Answer (score 23):

Using React Hooks:

UPDATE 2020-08-01: Amended with @ajrussellaudio's suggestion.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react"

const ShowPosts = () => {
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
    
    useEffect( () => { 
        async function fetchData() {
            try {
                const res = await axios.get('/posts'); 
                setPosts(res.data);
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        }
        fetchData();
    }, []);
    return <div>{posts}</div>
}
```

Comment: The `useEffect` callback cannot be `async`, as pointed out in [this article](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data) which is referenced in [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-can-i-do-data-fetching-with-hooks)

Comment: @ajrussellaudio but he can do like this...
useEffect(  () => {
async function fetchData(){
         try {
            const res = await axios.get('/posts');
            setPosts(res.data);
         } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
         }
}

fetchData();
     }, []);

Answer (score 1):

Poor me

For anyone using jest test

And trying to call a function children then received this Error

please check:

```
const children = jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce(null)
```

NOT

```
const children = jest.fn().mockRejectedValue(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use Next.js you can use this:
Put your codes in {}, if you have some connection or some calculations thats need time, add `await` to your codes in {}.

```
import { useEffect } from 'react'

useEffect(async () => {.......},[])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using **useState** and pass the setter function as a parameter to the async function that gets the posts from the server. Hope this helps.

```
function getPostElement(post, i){
    return <li key={i} className="list-group-item">{post.text}</li>;
}

async function getNewPosts(setPosts){
    const posts = await axios.get('/posts');
    const newPostElements =  posts.map((post,i) => getPostElement(post, i));

    setPosts(newPostElements);
}

function renderPosts(){
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
    getNewPosts(setPosts);

    return (
        <div>
            <ul className="list-group list-group-flush">
                {posts}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}
```