# How to render elements in react

Tags: reactjs, promise

I have this function which fetches a set of characters and images.

```
   const displayCharacters =  async () => { 
        if(filteredCharacters !== 'default'){
          const a = filteredCharacters.map(e => e.name);

          const options = {
            method: "POST",
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
            body: JSON.stringify({ 'data' : a })
          };

          const b = await fetch("/image",options)
          return b.json(); 

        }else{
          return [];
        }
      }
```

The html looks like this :

```
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form>
        <select name="movie" onChange ={handleMovieChange} value={selectedMovie}>
          <option value ="default">Please select a movie</option>
          {movieOptions()}
        </select>

        <select name="species" onChange={handleSpeciesChange} value={selectedSpecies}>
          <option value="default">Please select a species</option>
          {selectedMovie !== 'default' ? speciesOptions() : ''}
        </select>

        <select name="planets" onChange={handlePlanetChange} value={selectedPlanets}> 
          <option value="default">Please select a planet</option>
          {selectedSpecies !== 'default' ? planetOptions() : ''}
        </select> 
      </form>

      {displayCharacters().then(data=> data.map(char => (<div>{char.name}</div>)))}
    </div>

  );
}
```

But i get an error :

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object
>   Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an
>   array instead.

Comment: Your `displayCharacters` method is async, you need to put it in a `useEffect` (to not perform I/O on renders) and set some state in it to cause a re-render (useState). You can also use [suspense](https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-suspense.html) instead if you want this to be somewhat automated for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that React will not resolve a promise in the render. Initially your data fetching function will return a promise object rather than data, which React will not be able to render.

You'll need to set up state to hold first the placeholder data until the promise is resolved, then the data after promise resolution. Check this question for a good solution.

[Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise])](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47658765/objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child-found-object-promise/47659112)