# Trying to return data from a map method to my render and getting object error

Tags: reactjs

This has been asked here but it doesn't answer my question.[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47658765/objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child-found-object-promise)

I currently have a component that returns this method:

```
      return (
        <>
        { createDropdown() }
        </>
        )


 // create dropdown
const createDropdown = (data, parent) => {

  if(optionDetails) {
        return optionDetails.map((item, i) => {
            const fltData = filterData(item, props.items);
            return fltData.then(resultData => {
              return(
                <div>test</div>
              )
            })
          });
  }

}
```

My goal is to return a div with some html i there but I get the error:

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise])
```

In the question above they correct answer recommends setting state for the returned data.  I have dynamic data being created on `filterData()`I would rather not keep setting state for each one.  If that's the only way I'll do it but figured I'd ask to see if I can set something different.  Please let me know.

Comment: You would need to do this in a useEffect hook and then set state once your fetch has finished (like in the question you linked). I would map `optionDetails` to an array of promises returned by `filterData`, and then use `Promise.all()` to resolve all the promises. You can then map the array that you get from the resolved promise to divs and _then_ set the state

Comment: Your code is not looking correct. You are expecting **props.items** but I can't see from where you are getting that props. Can you plz update the code?