# Loop during API calls inside class

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react and I'm trying to figure out how to make only one Api call in my class, I could have used `useEffect` here but I want to learn to make it in a class. I'm working with Spotify API, I found a button `<SpotifyLogin />` which handle the connection to the API automatically and returns the `access_token`. After that, and only after, I want to make my API request. But when it enter inside the function, it loops inside it for decade. Then, thanks to stack people, I tried to use `async/await` in my request but new error

> Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

For the further explication, the project is a dashboard project with many API, so when you arrive on the main page, you have different login button, (spotify, twitter, facebook....) and by clicking on them, it connect the user directly to the API and load data from it.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import SpotifyLogin from 'react-spotify-login'
import axios from 'axios'
import '../style.css'
import Image from 'react-bootstrap/Image'
import SelectWidget from './SelectWidget'

class SpotLogin extends Component {
    state = {
        authData: {},
        userInfo: []
    }
    
    stockInfo = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            authData: e
        })
        console.log(this.state.authData.access_token)
    }

    getUserInfo = async() => {
        await axios('https://api.spotify.com/v1/me', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + this.state.authData.access_token}
        })
        .then(data => {
            this.setState({
                userInfo: data.data
            })
        })
        console.log("value ==>", this.state.userInfo)
        return (
            <div className="img-center">
                <h2>{this.state.userInfo.display_name}</h2>
            </div>
        )
    }

    render() {
        return( 
            Object.keys(this.state.authData).length === 0 ? (
                <div>
                    <SpotifyLogin clientId = 'ID'
                    redirectUri = 'http://localhost:3000/callback'
                    onSuccess={this.stockInfo}
                    buttonText= "Spotify"
                    className= "btn-spotify"
                    />
                </div>
                ) : 
            <div>
                {this.getUserInfo()}
            </div> 
        )
    }
}

export default SpotLogin
```

Comment: I think you need to check inside the useEffect if the user is logged in before making the request.

Comment: @BlackMath I thought about that, but the useEffect execute directly when I load the main page, so even if I check for the user, it will enter inside the useEffect but won't execute the api request. So it won't fill the json.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what @BlackMath say it's true
but it's also important to use with fetch call the async/await so your thread will not get stuck
then you should have an **isLoading** state that will block the render until you finish with fetch and then in the end you just need to do **setIsLoading(false)** something like this.

```
const [isLiading, setisLoading] = useState(true)

const stockInfo = (e) => {
    setToken(e.access_token)
}

useEffect(() => {
    axios('https://api.spotify.com/v1/me', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + token}
        })
        .then(data => {
            setUserInfo(data.data)
            console.log("value ==>", data.data);
        })
        .finally(()=>setIsLoading(false))
       
}, [])
 if(isLoading) return <h1>Loading....</h1>
  return (yourComponent)
```

like this you can block the render of the component until you finish.
And I used the finally instead of then because I want the loading to stop loading if it's rejected because then I can check the problem and work accordingly.

**Update**
for you problem you should look on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47658765/objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child-found-object-promise/47659112)
to short it if you don't wanna read:
then async await return a promise witch react will no render it

Comment: I refactored my code from arrow function to a class before trying your solution. The thing is that now that I'm using async/await, I got an error `Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

Comment: first why don't you sticl with functional component
seond why you didn't add the isLoading  state to stop the rendering