# How to render an asynchronous function in reactJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

My problem is as follows:

I have an asynchronous function that makes a mysql request and, depending on the result of the request, returns a different DIV.

```
const GetData = async (idAluno, disciplina) => {
  variavel = await confereInicial(idAluno, disciplina.id);
  //console.log(variavel); imprime direitinho, sem problemas

  if (variavel.data.length === 0) {
    return (
      <DivCheckBox
        dads={dados}
        nomeDisciplina={disciplina.title}
        labelDisciplina={disciplina.label}
        id={disciplina.id}
        inicial={0}
      />
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <DivCheckBox
        dads={dados}
        nomeDisciplina={disciplina.title}
        labelDisciplina={disciplina.label}
        id={disciplina.id}
        inicial={1}
      />
    );
  }
};
```

And this function is called several times (via a map) in the rendering part of the screen. Thus:

```
return (
  <div>
    {dados.state.nodesPadrao.map((p) => {
      return <GetData idAluno={1} disciplina={p} />;
    })}
  </div>
  ...
);
```

The problem is that when I compile, it appears "objects are not valid as react child (found: object Promise). If you want to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

What do I do?

Comment: you could put the promise into component lifecycle method (ex. componentDidMount() )  and use setState method to update the component state. The render method must be synchrone and rely on props and state only.

Comment: Q: How to render an asynchronous function in reactJS?  A: Leverage promises!  Duplicate question (with details on how to do this): [Objects are not valid as a React child (found: \[object Promise\])](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47658765/objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child-found-object-promise)

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the difference between a function (`GetData()`) and a function component (`<GetData .../>`).

Function components can't be `async`, since they implicitly always return a Promise, and you can't return a Promise from a component since you can't render a promise.

You'll need to use the `useEffect` hook to load the data at component mount time, then render things once it's loaded:

```
const GetData = ({idAluno, disciplina}) => {
  const [variavel, setVariavel] = React.useState(null);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    confereInicial(idAluno, disciplina.id).then(setVariavel);
  }, [idAluno, disciplina.id]);
  if (variavel === null) {
    // Still loading? You could also return `null` to not render anything.
    return <>Loading</>;
  }
  return (
    <DivCheckBox
      dads={dados}
      nomeDisciplina={disciplina.title}
      labelDisciplina={disciplina.label}
      id={disciplina.id}
      inicial={variavel.data.length === 0 ? 0 : 1}
    />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem yesterday. You shouldn't do async stuff in a render function.
You should either relay on the state or props.