# Objects are not valid as react child, but I'm using React docs official code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, next.js

As per the title, I am having trouble rendering a simple list of words in NextJs/React component.
I've gone thought the [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs) and tried their syntax, then I sifted through a large chunk of relevant questions on SO, but to no avail.
Here's the code I'm using:

```
const frequencies = async() => {
  var res = await fetch(`${process.env.baseUrl}/search-frequencies`, {
        
    method: 'post',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify({})
  })
  var queries = await res.json();
  var [tdm, freqs] = await queries
  //For Reference
  //freqs = [
  //[ 'bank', 1076 ],
  //[ 'maitane', 595 ],
  //[ 'sardon', 595 ],
  //[ 'mc', 553 ],
  //[ 'mansion', 540 ],
  //[ 'david', 530 ],
  //[ 'stocks', 513 ],
  //[ 'wighton', 480 ],
  //[ 'scott', 355 ],
  //[ 'cartney', 354 ]
  //]
  return freqs.map((item)=> {return <li key={item[0]}>{item[1]}</li>})
}
```

I've tried many different versions of the same code. But I keep on getting

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child

When I do a `console.log` inside of `frequencies`,
the object list instead of looking like:

```
<li> word1 </li>
<li> word2 </li>
...
```

looks like

```
[
  {
    '$$typeof': Symbol(react.element),
    type: 'li',
    key: 'bank',
    ref: null,
    props: { children: 1073 },
    _owner: null,
    _store: {}
  },<br>
  {
    '$$typeof': Symbol(react.element),
    type: 'li',
    key: 'maitane',
    ref: null,
    props: { children: 595 },
    _owner: null,
    _store: {}
  },
  ....
]
```

Comment: What does your `/search-frequencies` return as JSON? I assume the type makes `item[1]` end up as being an object instead of a string or number to be displayed.

Comment: A modern JS note: if you're using arrow functions, don't use curly brackets and `return` if your "function body" is a single statement: `freqs.map((item) => <li key={item[0]}>{item[1]}</li>)` works perfectly fine. Arrow functions automatically return whatever singular statement is to the right of the arrow. Of course, with that said: please show a [mcve] instead of just that single const-function, and show what's in `res` (also in minimal form. We don't need to see 100 identically shaped records).

Comment: Please show context for your code, ideally as [mre]. How and where are you calling `frequencies()`?

Comment: I edited the question. The issues I'm seeing are all in the `frequencies` function. Does this clarify anything?

Comment: You didn't clarify anything. How and where are you calling `frequencies()`?

Comment: Here's a fixed sandbox including a useEffect that reproduces the issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-dawn-66s6k?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I'm confused, that sandbox's comment explains exactly what the issue is, you are adding a promise to instead of the result of the promise, doesn't that mean you've answered your own question?

Comment: @ChrisG you are a gentleman and a scholar. Thanks!

Comment: Also, add the code as an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: Googled the error and immediately found an exact duplicate: [Objects are not valid as a React child (found: \[object Promise\])](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47658765/objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child-found-object-promise)