# How can I get more information/resolve "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise])"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, discord, next.js, next-auth

I've been working with the [next-auth](https://next-auth.js.org) package try implement Discord OAuth2 into my website. While I've nearly finished integration, I am struggling with an error that has been popping up that I cannot identify. I'm getting `Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.` on *every* rebuild, without an further information. I've looked through my code and I can't find where this is happening, I'm guessing it's happening on `_app.js`. From what I've seen it could also be due to using an async function, but I'm not sure how to work with that. [(Relevant post)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47658765/objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child-found-object-promise)

`_app.js`

```js
import 'tailwindcss/tailwind.css';
import Head from 'next/head';
import { SessionProvider } from 'next-auth/react';
import Nav from '../components/Nav';

export default function App({
  Component,
  pageProps: { session, ...pageProps },
}) {
  return (
    <SessionProvider session={session}>

      <>
        <Head>
          <title>Status+</title>

        </Head>
        <div className="container-fluid mx-auto w-full scrollhost" id="container4">

          <Nav> </Nav>
          <main className="scrollhost" id="container2">
            <Component {...pageProps} />
          </main>
        </div>
      </>

    </SessionProvider>
  )
}
```

`index.js`

```js
import Head from 'next/head';

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center min-h-screen py-2">
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <main className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center w-full flex-1 px-20 text-center">
        <h1>Hello World.</h1>
      </main>

    </div>
  );
}
```

`Nav.jsx`

```
import Link from 'next/link';
import axios from 'axios';

import { useSession, signIn, signOut } from 'next-auth/react';

async function returnSignIn() {
  const { data: session } = useSession();

  if (!session) {
    return (
      <button onClick={() => signIn()} className="btn btn-primary">Sign In</button>

    );
  }
  const { accessToken } = session;

  const profileData = await fetch('https://discord.com/api/users/@me', {
    headers: {
      authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
    },
  });
  const newData = await profileData.json();
  console.log(newData);

  if (!newData) {
    return (
      <button onClick={() => signIn()} className="btn btn-primary">Sign In</button>

    );
  }
  return (
    <p>E</p>
  );
}

const Nav = async () => (
  <div className="navbar z-10 top-0 fixed shadow-lg bg-neutral text-neutral-content inset-x-0 bg-opacity-80 backdrop-filter backdrop-blur-lg">
    <div className="px-2 mx-2 navbar-start">
      <span className="text-lg font-bold">
        Status+
      </span>
    </div>
    <div className="hidden px-2 mx-2 navbar-center lg:flex">
      <div className="flex items-stretch">
        <div className="btn btn-ghost btn-sm rounded-btn">
          <Link href="/">
            Home
          </Link>
        </div>
        <div className="btn btn-ghost btn-sm rounded-btn">
          <Link href="/">
            Status
          </Link>
        </div>
        <div className="btn btn-ghost btn-sm rounded-btn">
          <Link href="/">
            Dashboard
          </Link>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="navbar-end">
      {returnSignIn()}

    </div>

  </div>
);
export default Nav;
```

Where is this error happening? Is there a way to get a better Stack Trace so I can debug what is going on here? Thanks!

EDIT: Per the suggestion below, I've tried this code using `useEffect` without luck:

```js
import Link from 'next/link';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useSession, signIn, signOut } from 'next-auth/react';

async function returnSignIn() {
  const { data: session } = useSession();

  if (!session) {
    return (
      <button onClick={() => signIn()} className="btn btn-primary">Sign In</button>

    );
  }
  const { accessToken } = session;

  const [profileData, setProfileData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const importantData = await fetch('https://discord.com/api/users/@me', {
        headers: {
          authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        },
      });
      const newData = await importantData.json();
      setProfileData(newData);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  if (!profileData) {
    return (
      <button onClick={() => signIn()} className="btn btn-primary">Sign In</button>

    );
  }
  return (
    <p>E</p>
  );
}

const Nav = async () => (
  <div className="navbar z-10 top-0 fixed shadow-lg bg-neutral text-neutral-content inset-x-0 bg-opacity-80 backdrop-filter backdrop-blur-lg">
    <div className="px-2 mx-2 navbar-start">
      <span className="text-lg font-bold">
        Status+
      </span>
    </div>
    <div className="hidden px-2 mx-2 navbar-center lg:flex">
      <div className="flex items-stretch">
        <div className="btn btn-ghost btn-sm rounded-btn">
          <Link href="/">
            Home
          </Link>
        </div>
        <div className="btn btn-ghost btn-sm rounded-btn">
          <Link href="/">
            Status
          </Link>
        </div>
        <div className="btn btn-ghost btn-sm rounded-btn">
          <Link href="/">
            Dashboard
          </Link>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="navbar-end">
      {returnSignIn()}

    </div>

  </div>
);
export default Nav;
```

Comment: you should use `useEffect` to call APIs, calling fetch on the top level of a component is making it return a promise

Comment: @RameshReddy thanks, where can I find documentation/where should this be used?

Comment: reactjs.org or search for "handling side effects in useEffect"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Objects are not valid as a React child (found: \[object Promise\])](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47658765/objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child-found-object-promise)

Comment: Seems useful, but I'd prefer to continue to use async as I don't want the page to continue rendering until I receive data- unless this isn't the way I should do it?

Comment: You can declare and call async functions inside `useEffect`. Give it a try and update the question with what you've tried.

Comment: Sure, I'll give it a shot thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239282/discussion-between-fxllencode-and-ramesh-reddy).

Comment: You need to remove the `async` from your `returnSignIn` component declaration.