# Async promise function not working in NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am still fairly new to working with async and await functions, and even newer to implementing promise functions. I am trying to print out whatever my asynchronous function returns. When I log the output to the console, it always shows me the correct output, but when I try to save it and return it, it only works every other go. I have this similar code in react and it seems to work fine on the first go there, but with NextJs I am running into the issue that it does not run on the first go but second. I am attaching my code and would appreciate a general direction for where I can go to solve this issue.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { getStockPrice } from '../configs/stockapi';

function HomeInvestment() {
  const [entered, setEntered] = useState(false);
  const [ticker, setTicker] = useState('');

  
  const [price, setPrice] = useState(0);
  const [checks, setChecks] = useState([])

  const clear = () => {
    setEntered(false);
    setChecks([])
  }

  const handleSubmit = async() => {
    const idT = document.getElementById('t');
    console.log(ticker);  
    const p = stockPrice(ticker).then(result => {

      let data = {
        ticker: ticker,
        price: result
      }
      setChecks([...checks, data])
      setPrice(p);
    })
    setEntered(true);
    console.log(checks);
    idT.value = null
  }

  const stockPrice = async(ticker) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      getStockPrice(ticker)
      .then(result => {
        console.log(result)
        resolve(result.toFixed(2))
      })
      .catch(error => {
        reject(error)
      })
    })
    
  }

  return (
    <div className='flex justify-center'>
        <div className='w-full max-w-[40ch] bg-white shadow-md rounded px-8 pt-6 pb-8 mb-4'>
          <div className='flex text-black justify-center flex-col bg-slate-300 px-2 py-3 rounded mb-6'>
              <div className='mb-4'>
                <label className="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2 text-center" >
                    Enter Stock Ticker
                </label>
                <input id= 't' required className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"  type="text" placeholder="Stock Ticker" onChange={(e) => setTicker(e.target.value)}/>
              
              </div>
              <button className='bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded-full focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline mx-10 ' type="button" onClick={handleSubmit}>
                Check Stock Info
              </button>
          </div>

          {entered && 
            <div>
              <div className=''>
                <button onClick={clear} className="text-red-600">Clear</button>  
              </div>
              <div className='flex text-black justify-center flex-col bg-slate-300 px-2 py-3 rounded'>
                  {checks.forEach((element) => {
                    return (
                      <div>
                        <p>{element.ticker}</p>
                        <p>{element.price}</p>
                      </div>
                    )
                  })}
                  {price}
              </div>
            </div>
          }

        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default HomeInvestment
```

Comment: Which exact part of your code is not working as you expect it to? What's the flow you're expecting?

Comment: It's a good idea when working with Promise stuff and the new `async` syntax to *always* use that, and not use the old `.then()` etc Promise API. That's what the `async` syntax features are meant to simplify.

Comment: It appears that the getStockPrice function is not returning a Promise, or is not being treated as one.

Comment: Why don't you use `async` with `await`? https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-feather-t2heml?file=/src/HomeInvestment.js:50-63 Can you replicate your code here?

Comment: `const stockPrice = async (ticker) => {
    return getStockPrice(ticker)
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
      })
      .catch((error) => {});
  };` Or   `const stockPrice = async (ticker) => {
    return await getStockPrice(ticker)
      };`

Comment: I want to be able to enter a stock ticker, then the handle submit would fetch the stock data, put it into an object, and then push that object into an array which I can map through to render live. @KevinPastor

Comment: When I run that version of the code, I get this error: Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead. @DreamBold

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47658765/objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child-found-object-promise can you have a look at this thread?

Comment: @DreamBold the reason I am confused is when I console log the result of the function in a different file where the function is actually made, it prints the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After removing all the noise coming from your specific use case, it seems like you might have a problem understanding the concept of a Promise. A Promise is an object that promises you that it will return a value at some point. You first need to wait for the promise to give you a value in order to manipulate it. The *old* way of handling Promises was with the function properties `then` and `catch`, but you should now be using the `async` and `await` keywords.

Reading the new implementation of `handleSubmit`, we are first waiting for `getStockPrice` to give a new price value before manipulating the value we're given. After the Promise has *resolved*, we can do whatever we want with the value. In your specific case, we're updating the state of the component.

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import { getStockPrice } from '../configs/stockapi'

const HomeInvestment = () => {
  const [entered, setEntered] = useState(false)
  const [ticker, setTicker] = useState('')

  const [price, setPrice] = useState(0)
  const [checks, setChecks] = useState([])

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setTicker(event.target.value)
  }

  const handleSubmit = async () => {
    const newPrice = await getStockPrice(ticker)
    const formattedNewPrice = newPrice.toFixed(2)

    const check = {
      ticker,
      price: formattedNewPrice,
    }
    setChecks([...checks, check])
    setPrice(formattedNewPrice)
    setEntered(true)

    const idT = document.getElementById('t')
    idT.value = null
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <label>Enter Stock Ticker</label>
          <input id="t" required type="text" placeholder="Stock Ticker" onChange={handleChange} />
        </div>
        <button type="button" onClick={handleSubmit}>
          Check Stock Info
        </button>
      </div>

      {entered && (
        <div>
          {checks.map((check) => (
            <div>
              <p>{check.ticker}</p>
              <p>{check.price}</p>
            </div>
          ))}
          {price}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}

export default HomeInvestment
```

One other thing to note is the fact that you were using `Array.forEach` instead of `Array.map` inside of your `return` statement. Using the second one will actually display some data for each of the array's entry on screen.

I haven't actually tested this component, but this should get you started. Watch out for the DOM manipulation you're doing with `document.getElementById`; you should probably look into `useRef`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, this works for the most part. When I originally tried to implement it, it was only returning 0's, but after I added a console.log statement printing out the price, it became the correct price. How do I avoid this if I  were to want to remove the console.log

Comment: another issue that I am running into is when I am using a stock that I havent used before, it prints out the correct price but does not save it, and instead submits a 0. how do i avoid that

Comment: "*but you should now be using the async and await keywords.*" I disagree on this. There are some circumstances in which promise chaining is more convenient for the job and vice versa.

Comment: @Dotman If this solved your issue, I think you could mark my answer as the accepted one.