# React JS async component

Tags: reactjs, async-await

I have this component

```
import React from 'react'

export const MainPage = async () => {
 let resp =  await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/users/63fc9a335a6f38aa2dd47d15`, {
      method: 'get',
      headers: { 'x-access-token': 123 }
    });
let user = await resp.json();
  
  return (
    <div>MainPage
      
    </div>
  )
}


export default MainPage;
```

And I call her on the app:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <MainPage/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Then I get this error:
**Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.**

I understand it's because the function returns a promise but I don't know how to call it another way.
Would appreciate help.

Comment: Remove the `async` keyword

Comment: Sounds like an X/Y problem - what are you really trying to do? You can't just make a component a Promise.

Comment: I have an asynchronous call inside the function. (I removed the code in the question because I wanted it to be cleaner) I am correcting the question.

Comment: @Maxima please include the code for that so we can answer accordingly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Objects are not valid as a React child (found: \[object Promise\])](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47658765/objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child-found-object-promise)

Answer (score 2):

React components can't be async. You should move your code to fetch to a useEffect with an empty dependency array.

```
export const MainPage = () => {
  const [resp, setResp] = React.useState(undefined);

  React.useEffect(async () => {
    const resp = await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/users/63fc9a335a6f38aa2dd47d15`, {
      method: 'get',
      headers: { 'x-access-token': 123 }
    });
    setResp(await res.json());
  }, []);

  if (!resp) {
    // Optional: make it show something else while the request is still loading.
    return <div>Loading</div>;
  }
  
  return (
    <div>MainPage</div>
  )
}
```

Comment: What does that mean? The function will return "Loading data" until there is a value in the user?

Comment: @Maxima Yes, that's correct.

Comment: this does not work. useEffort requires a function that returns a function, whereas this is returns a promise.

Answer (score 1):

`async` cannot be used with function components.

use the `useState` hook to set the data once it is fetched, and display it in the component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const fetchData = async () => {
  const resp = await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/users/63fc9a335a6f38aa2dd47d15`, {
    method: 'get',
    headers: { 'x-access-token': 123 }
  });
  const data = await resp.json();
  return data;
};

const MainPage = () => {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData().then(data => setUserData(data));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {userData ? (
        <div>
          <h1>MainPage</h1>
          <img src={userData.picture} alt="User" />
          <p>Contact Information: {userData.contactInfo}</p>
          <button>{userData.buttonText}</button>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <p>Loading data...</p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default MainPage;
```

Comment: This is how it works:
```
 function MainPage()  {
  const [userName, setuserName] = useState(null);
  let resp;
  useEffect(() => {
     (async () => {
      resp =  await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/users/${id}`, {
        method: 'get',
        headers: { 'x-access-token': token }
      });
      const user = await resp.json();;
      setuserName(user['First Name'] + ' ' + user['Last Name']);
    })()
  }, [])
 return (
      <div> {userName ? <div>data...</div> 
 :
        <p>Loading data...</p>
       }
      </div>
    )
}
export default MainPage;

  
```

Answer (score 1):

Aspornoy's response is wrong. You can not use async function in useEffect.

❌ don't do this

```
// ❌ don't do this
useEffect(async () => {
  const data = await fetchData();
}, [fetchData])
```

do this

```
useEffect(() => {
  // declare the data fetching function
  const fetchData = async () => {
    const data = await fetch('https://yourapi.com');
  }

  // call the function
  fetchData()
    // make sure to catch any error
    .catch(console.error);
}, [])
```