How can fetch youtube transcriptions in next.js
"use client";

import { useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";

function VideoCreado() {
    const searchParmas = useSearchParams();
    const link = searchParmas.get("link");
    return (
        <div className="bg-gray-900 text-gray-100 min-h-screen flex flex-col items-center justify-center">
            <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold mb-4">video created!</h1>
            <p className="text-lg">transcript:</p>
            <p>{link}</p>
        </div>
    );
}

export default VideoCreado;

how can I use youtube API in next.js such that I can fetch the transcription of the youtube video with link = {link}?
I know how to do this in python but not in tsx:
from youtube_transcript_api import YouTubeTranscriptApi

def get_transcription(video_url):
    # Extract the video ID from the URL
    video_id = video_url.split("v=")[1]
    ampersand_position = video_id.find("&")
    if ampersand_position != -1:
        video_id = video_id[:ampersand_position]

    # Get the transcript
    transcript = YouTubeTranscriptApi.get_transcript(video_id)
    
    # Combine the transcription into a single string
    transcription = ' '.join([entry['text'] for entry in transcript])
    return transcription

# Example usage
video_url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8yZ-x-WuFw0&ab_channel=NamePointer"
transcription = get_transcription(video_url)
print(transcription)


You would need to use ytdl-core in order to get the transcript.
See this entry on GitHub for a code example.
With the code shared on the link above, I was able to create a minimal working example - see it working here on replit - you will see the captions on the console, but, I wasn't able to render the string on the website - since I really don't know about next.js - I bet you can modify the code and make it work as you need.
Here is the code sample:
"use client";

import { useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";
import ytdl from "ytdl-core";
import axios from "axios";
import { XMLParser, XMLBuilder, XMLValidator } from "fast-xml-parser";

// Get transcript of the given video.
// Sources: 
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/56213291/4092887
// https://github.com/fent/node-ytdl-core/discussions/1088
const getSubTitles = async (url: string) => {
  var first_transcript = "";

  try {
    const parser = new XMLParser();
    console.log("URL!!: " + url);

    const info = await ytdl.getInfo(url);
    if (!info.player_response.captions) return null;
    const tracks =
      info.player_response.captions.playerCaptionsTracklistRenderer
        .captionTracks;

    if (!tracks || !tracks.length) {
      return "No tracks";
    } else {
      //console.log(tracks);
      //return "Ok!";

      const parsedTracks = await Promise.all(
        tracks.map(async (track) => ({
          lang: track.languageCode,
          content: parser.parse((await axios.get(track.baseUrl)).data, {}),
        })),
      );

      //console.log(typeof parsedTracks[0]["content"]["transcript"]["text"]); // object!

      // Get the data from the object and build the string: 
      for (var i = 0; i < parsedTracks[0]['content']['transcript']['text'].length; i++) {
        first_transcript += parsedTracks[0]['content']['transcript']['text'][i] + "\n";
      }
      
      console.log("Captions:\n");
      console.log(first_transcript);
      return first_transcript;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("Exception happened:\n");
    console.log(e);
    first_transcript = e;
    return first_transcript;
  }
};

function VideoCreado () {
  var link = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8yZ-x-WuFw0";
  var transcript_full = ""; // Store here the result of the async "getSubTitles" function - in order to see it on the website.

  // Call the async function to get the data: 
  getSubTitles(link);

  return (
    <div className="bg-gray-900 text-gray-100 min-h-screen flex flex-col items-center justify-center">
      <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold mb-4">video created!</h1>
      <p className="text-lg">Link:</p>
      <p>{link}</p>
      <br />
      <p className="text-lg">transcript:</p>
      <p>{transcript_full}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

Response - screenshot:

Response - sample in the console:
> my-app@0.1.0 dev
> next dev --port 3000 --hostname 0.0.0.0

   ▲ Next.js 14.1.0
   - Local:        http://localhost:3000
   - Network:      http://0.0.0.0:3000

 ✓ Ready in 2.1s
 ○ Compiling / ...
 ✓ Compiled / in 1895ms (299 modules)
URL!!: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8yZ-x-WuFw0
Captions:

as you could tell from my last video I
started to add some tiles to my content
so that everyone can understand me
despite my terrible accent and as shown
by the results of the poll I created you
guys seem to like them however editing
the subtitles in one by one is tedious
and takes a lot of time so I wanted to
automate the process by having the
computer automatically create them using
the transcripts I write for every video
before recording the voiceover before
...

